# Javascript references aren't working ASP.NET Development Server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-development-serv

I'm not sure what's going on here. I've reformed the links in every way I can think of to try and reference my Script libraries, but nothing seems to work.

When I upload it to my web host it works fine, locally it doesn't work at all.

The weirdest part is, it references my CSS files fine and nothing else seems to have any issues.

```
//Works
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
//Doesn't work
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm not sure what could be going on here or really even where to debug from here. I've tried removing the `@Url.Content(...)` and pointing directly to the directory, but that doesn't do anything at all. Hopefully someone else has run into this issue and has figured out a solution.

Using: ASP.NET MVC3 Razor, Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered page in a browser? What was output for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the default directory setup then your `Scripts` folder is a sub-directory of the `Content` folder; in which case:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: I am using default directory setup, I forgot to mention that. But, they aren't contained under /Content/Scripts. They are under /Views/Shared/Scripts. I have also tried moving them to the /Content/Scripts directory, which also does not work.

Comment: Bah, moved them back to the /Content/Scripts directory. I must have had a typo before. /facepalm... thank you :)